# Measure mobile data usage from a particular point of time

Tags: android, mobile-data

I want to use a service to measure the mobile data used since that service is started but I'm only able to measure the mobile data since device boot using the methods getTotalRxBytes() and getTotalTxBytes() of the TrafficStats class. Can someone help me in measuring the data used when the button is clicked and the service is started?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private long data_limit;
EditText et_data_limit;
Button btn_start_track;
private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("Data measured", PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putLong("data", 0);

    if(isPermissionAllowed()){

    }
    else{
        requestPermission();
    }

    et_data_limit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_data_limit);
    btn_start_track = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start_track);

    btn_start_track.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data_limit = Long.parseLong(et_data_limit.getText().toString());
            data_limit = data_limit * 1024;

            Log.i("enter", String.valueOf(data_limit));

            //data_limit = data_limit + sharedPreferences.getLong("data", 0);

            editor.putLong("data", data_limit);
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataTracking.class);
            intent.putExtra("data limit", data_limit);

            MainActivity.this.startService(intent);
        }
    });
}

private boolean isPermissionAllowed() {
    //Getting the permission status
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE);
    int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE);

    //If permission is granted returning true
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return true;

    //If permission is not granted returning false
    return false;
}

private void requestPermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) &&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) &&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)){
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }

    //And finally ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
    Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE},STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}

//This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){

        //If permission is granted
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied! App may not work properly",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

DataTracking.java

```
public class DataTracking extends Service {

private long data_limit;
private long data_used;

public DataTracking(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    data_limit = intent.getExtras().getLong("data limit");
    Log.i("data", String.valueOf(data_limit));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    onHandleIntent(intent);

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    TrafficStats trafficStats = new TrafficStats();

    long mtx = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
    long mrx = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();

    data_used = mtx + mrx;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data_used + "-" + data_limit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(data_used >= data_limit){
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

        try{
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Method setMobileDataStatus = telephonyManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setDataEnabled", boolean.class);

            if (null != setMobileDataStatus){
                setMobileDataStatus.invoke(telephonyManager, false);
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you save the data when the service starts, and compare that with the data used on button click? Or vice versa. Basically take the difference between two measurement points.

Comment: I can try that, yes :)